# Keep PHP email form from showing a blank page

Tags: php, email

I am trying to use some code I found online, but I don't know PHP. The form works, but after successfully sending an email, the browser URL window is set to the PHP file and I can only figure out how to write plain text in that area. What i would like to do is either have a redirect to the current html page or, ideally, use some jQuery to replace the contents of the  tag with some text.

Thank you in advance for any help!

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "email@email.email";
    $email_subject = "contact from website";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['t_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['t_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $t_name = $_POST['t_name']; // required
    $t_interest = $_POST['t_interest']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$t_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$t_interest)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Interest you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }





    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($t_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Interests: ".clean_string($t_interest)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 

?>
function redirect(){
window.location.href = "http://getoutsideutah.org/donate.html";
}

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not let PHP do the redirect after your mail function? `header('Location: http://getoutsideutah.org/donate.html');`

Comment: If you want to use that redirect, you need to put it between `<script>` tags

Comment: Do not use the error suppression operator `@` unless you like having your code stop working for no apparent reason because you suppressed the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a location header with the new URL you want to go to:

```
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

header("Location: http://getoutsideutah.org/donate.html");
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! (and Dave!). This works well, but kicks the user back to the previous page without giving them any sort of feedback about their message being sent successfully. Is there a way to do that instead?

Comment: Well, you could store a message in a session, but given you said you don't know PHP, maybe you could just create a `thanks.html` page and redirect there instead of back to the `donate.html` page.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "email@email.email";
    $email_subject = "contact from website";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['t_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['t_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }



    $t_name = $_POST['t_name']; // required
    $t_interest = $_POST['t_interest']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$t_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$t_interest)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Interest you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }





    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($t_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Interests: ".clean_string($t_interest)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

redirect();

```
?>
function redirect(){
header("Location:http://getoutsideutah.org/donate.html");
}

<?php
}
?>
```